# TypeError: Failed to fetch

Tags: java, api, cors, swagger

**ENDPOINT**

Hola a todos estoy que apunto a la siguiente URL -> [Enlace Aqui](https://clientes-dev.cla.pe/api/v1.0/claroclubclientes2)

**MENSAJE**

```
curl -X POST "https://clientes-dev.cla.pe/api/v1.0/claroclubclientes2" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "access_token: f88ec930-cd78-4009-a3c3-9b90964949ff" -H "idTransaccion: 111" -H "Origin: *" -H "msgid: appClaroClub" -H "userId: 1" -H "timestamp: 2018-27-11T11:38:00Z" -d "{ \"MessageRequest\": { \"Header\": { \"HeaderRequest\": { \"consumer\": \"\", \"country\": \"PE\", \"dispositivo\": \"APK MOVIL\", \"language\": \"ES\", \"modulo\": \"claroclubclientes\", \"msgType\": \"Request\", \"operation\": \"consultar\", \"pid\": \"205010110001\", \"system\": \"APPMICLARO\", \"timestamp\": \"2017-12-29T09:09:09.000Z\", \"userId\": \"USRTCRM\", \"wsIp\": \"192.168.58.20\" } }, \"Body\": { \"msisdn\": 989837641, \"tipoDocumento\": \"\", \"numeroDocumento\": \" \" } }}"
```

**PROBLEMATICA**

al momento de mandar el mensaje curl que genera el swagger, por qué sale TypeError: Failed to fetch? a que se debe ?

Comment: Te diste cuenta que incluiste un access token en la url que posteaste?

Comment: Que hay de malo con poner un access token como header ?